# How to install all dependencies of a CPAN module?

Tags: perl, cpan

How to install all dependencies of the module Nmap::Scanner with cpan in Perl? I did, cpan Nmap::Scanner. But, needing other dependencies for module.

```
  #!/bash/perl

  use Nmap::Scanner;
  my $scan = Nmap::Scanner->new();
  
  $scan->add_target('localhost');
  $scan->add_target('host.i.administer');
  $scan->add_scan_port('1-1024');
  $scan->add_scan_port('31337');
  $scan->tcp_syn_scan();
  $scan->noping();
  
  my $results = $scan->scan();
  
  my $hosts = $results->gethostlist();
  
  while (my $host = $hosts->get_next()) {
  
      print "On " . $host->hostname() . ": \n";
  
      my $ports = $host->get_port_list();
  
      while (my $port = $ports->get_next()) {
          print join(' ',
              'Port',
              $port->service() . '/' . $port->portid(),
              'is in state',
              $port->state(),
              "\n"
          );
      }
  
  }
```

I did, but when running the script in perl, shows this in console.

```
Can't locate XML/SAX/Exception.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl` /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/SAX/ParserFactory.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/XML/SAX/ParserFactory.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Nmap/Scanner/Backend/XML.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Nmap/Scanner/Backend/XML.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Nmap/Scanner/Scanner.pm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Nmap/Scanner/Scanner.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Nmap/Scanner.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Nmap/Scanner.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at e1-insecure.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at e1-insecure.pl line 3.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cpan` resolves dependencies automatically. To install execute the following command:

```
cpan Nmap::Scanner
```

An alternative installer for CPAN modules is [`cpanminus`](https://raw.github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/master/cpanm). Using `cpanm`:

```
cpanm Nmap::Scanner
```

Comment: Then maybe you need to: `cpan XML::SAX::Exception`

Comment: now shows this, "Can't locate Class/Generate.pm ??"  >> cpan Class:Generate .. y listo, gracias amigo